# Regex for multiline .ini file

Tags: regex, ini

I try to create a regex expression that can parse a ini-File.

But I want that the ini-values can be multiline!

Like that:

```
Wert1=Hallo
dsadasd
Wert2=Hi
Wert3=Heinirch Volland
```

I try it with this regex, but it doesn't work:

```
/.*=(.*)^.*=/gsm
```

Comment: What do you mean, it "doesn't work"? It doesn't match at all?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Try [`/^([^=\r\n]+)=(.+(?:\r?\n(?![^=\r\n]+=).*)*)/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/fdlP42/1). If the keys can only consist of word chars, use [`/^(\w+)=(.+(?:\r?\n(?!\w+=).*)*)/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/fXzJxA/1). There are ready INI parsing libraries for programming languages though, it is best to use one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be using this PCRE regex :

```
/^.*=.*[^=]*$/gm
```

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/fGeZLN/4).

This relies on the absence of the `s`ingle-line flag, be careful not to set it. The `m`ultiline flag is also necessary, and `g`lobal can be used if appropriate.

This matches from the start of a line containing an equal sign (`^.*=.*`), then will match as many whole lines that do not contain an equal sign as it can (`[^=]*$`, where `[^=]` will match linefeeds).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to get all ini values, and to do that you can use this regex pattern:

```
/^(.*)=(.*)/gm
```

and you'll can access your values using groups, each group will retrieve to you key and value

Comment: This won't match multiline values without the `s`ingle-line flag, and will match too greedily with it

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using Perl. Have you considered using [Config::IniFiles](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Config-IniFiles-2.94/lib/Config/IniFiles.pm)? That module will handle parsing INI-type files for you, and has support for multiline parameters using heredoc syntax:

```
Parameter=<<EOT
value/line 1
value/line 2
EOT
```

Or, if you enable it with `Config::IniFiles->new(..., -allowcontinue => 1);`, continuation lines:

```
[Section]
Parameter=this parameter \
  spreads across \
  a few lines
```